# Edit/remove wp_dashboard_recent_drafts()

Tags: dashboard

I'd like to remove the draft post form the widget "Quick draft" in the dashboard (admin panel).
I want to see the small editor (quick draft), but I don't want to show the list of the last draft.

The relative function to remove/edit is [`wp_dashboard_recent_drafts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dashboard_recent_drafts/)

It's in `/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated answer:*

Let's modify the corresponding *dashboard* query so it returns no *draft* posts.

### Example:

If I recall correctly the default *Hello World* post has `ID=1` and the default *Sample Page* has `ID=2`.

So if we set `ID=2`, then we can remove the draft list, since it is fetching the `post` post type.

Since WordPress 4.4 (see [#8243](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8243)) the `dashboard_recent_drafts_query_args` filter is available, that makes it easy to target only the relevant query:

```
/**
 * Remove recent post drafts under the Quick Draft on the dashboard
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/201910/26350
 */
add_filter( 'dashboard_recent_drafts_query_args', function( $args )
{
    // Adjust parameters to your needs to return empty results
    $args['post_type'] = 'post'; 
    $args['p'] = 2; 

    return $args;
} );
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs, with other parameters if needed.

Another way would be to use `$args['post__in'] = [0];` to generate the `wp_posts.ID IN (0)` WHERE part. I think I've seen this approach in some answers here on this site, but don't recall where. We get the same result if we use  `null`, `''` or even `false` in place of `0` because it's [taken through](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c376477265c248b590e2189252b7a24bc8e46966/wp-includes/query.php#L2764) `absint()` via `array_map()`.

This is the result:

[image: quick draft]

Comment: Ok perfect.
I tried also to copy and rename the function `wp_dashboard_quick_press()` in my functions.php, so I didn't recall `wp_dashboard_recent_drafts()`. It's ok.
If I'd like to save draft in a post type? For example I have the custom post type "events" and I'd like to write an event from quick draft in the dashboard?

Comment: yes, other possibility would be create a custom dashboard widget by copying code from the core and put in a custom plugin. But the core code can change in the future, so I prefer this shorter method ;-) I haven't looked into the Quick Draft form, to see if it's possible to change the cpt. I think that would be better deserved as a new question. @Gloria

Comment: Ok... I'll open a new question...
So I've another problem. When I click on the "save draft" button, the fields are not cleared... Do I open another question or can we solve here?

Comment: oh, I didn't test to post a draft ;-) It's loaded again via ajax. Please check out the updated the answer. @Gloria

Answer (score 1):

Would you be happy just to hide it? If so:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_quickdrafts');

function hide_quickdrafts() {
  echo '<style>
    #dashboard_quick_press .drafts {
    display:none;
    } 
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: It's a solution...